# How can the state in react-js turns back to their original value

Tags: reactjs

I'm exploring state in ReactJS and encountered this problem. What I want to happen is when the `state === 0` it will go back to its original value. Here's my code:

```
export default class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      stateValue: 5
    }
  }
```

And inside `componentDidUpdate()` is I decrement the value of state by 1 and have a condition in `setState` but I don't know what to put inside `setState` in order for the state to come back to its original value again.

```
if (stateValue === 0) {
  this.setState({ })
}
```

and inside return is

```
    <div>
       <h1>{stateValue}</h1>
    </div>
```

The result is it counts from 5 down to 0 but when it gets 0. It doesn't change back to its original value.

What I want to happen is when it turns to 0 it will go back to its value again which is 5 then continue to count down again. How can I do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share  your working code  with https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: Nothing wrong with just putting `this.setState({ stateValue: 5 });` there to set it back to 5. if you want to be a tad cleaner you can save its original value somewhere and then use that instead of hardcoding 5.

Answer (score 2):

You can store another property in your set state.

```
export default class Test extends React.Component {
  const originalValue = 5;

  constructor (props) {
     super(props);
     this.state ={
       stateValue: originalValue
     }
  }
}
```

And then while updating you can assign that property

```
if (stateValue === 0) {
    this.setState({ stateValue: originalValue })
}
```

Comment: you shouldnt keep everything in component state, its not a place for constants and for stuff that does not participate in render logic. For that you should use class properties

Comment: Yes, thats true. Thanks for pointing it out. Since it is not updating or sent to a different component, I can reuse my variable directly while updating.

Answer (score 1):

You can impliment this kind of logic with initial state with class property:

```
class Example extends Component {
  defaultState = {
    stateValue: 5,
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.defaultState;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(_prevProps, _prevState) {
    if (this.state.stateValue === 0) {
      this.setState(this.defaultState);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { stateValue } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{stateValue}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```